Even without the checkbox, are SE's changes legal?
This relates to StackExchange's planned changes to the data dump process: Announcing a change to the data-dump process
One important point that I haven't seen anyone mention is that, in order to download the data dump, you need to create an account. In order to create an account, you need to agree to SE's Terms of Service and and Privacy Policy.
This, in addition to the checkbox which requires users to agree to something more, seems to be a violation of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license:

No downstream restrictions . You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, the Licensed Material if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material.

Isn't forcing users to create an account a violation of this term, even if the text on the checkbox is removed?

@W.O. 1. SE can't impose additional legal measures; 2. The terms and conditions are legal measures; 3. Creating an account requires agreeing to the terms and conditions; therefore 4. Forcing users to create an account to access the data dump imposes additional legal measures, which is in violation of the CC BY-SA 4.0 License? Not a perfect syllogism, but I hope it gets my thinking across

I think this fits better on [law.se].

@2br-2b They can't impose "any additional or different terms or conditions on ...  the Licensed Material, if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material." You need to explain how any terms/conditions restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights once you have actually received the Licensed Material. They can put whatever restrictions they want on who they deliver the Licensed Material to. They just can't restrict the exercise of the Licensed Rights once someone has a copy.

SE is just "choosing who they give their nice package of the data to". I don't think any law prevents you from choosing who you give something to. If you download the data and give it to a friend, no law will force you to now give it to everyone in the universe because you gave it to a friend. The checkbox may be illegal, but requiring signing up, I don't think so.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog here's the question on law.SE: Can one distribute data requiring users to sign some non-commercial use agreement and then still add a CC BY-SA license on that downloaded data?

I addressed this in part of my answer to the original post on the changes to the data dump process.
The Creative Commons license only takes effect when content is distributed. Accepting browsewrap terms of service or needing to accept clickwrap terms of service prior to accessing the content is allowed. You can put any barriers up that you want before the CC-licensed material can be accessed. However, once a person has CC-licensed material, the CC license applies.
The checkbox, or even removing the checkbox and adding other license conditions is problematic, but I don't think it's necessarily illegal. This is a supplemental agreement. When describing supplemental agreements in their FAQ, Creative Commons uses phrases like "should not do so in such a way that would neutralize terms of the CC license" and "to avoid confusing those who may mistakenly believe the work is licensed under standard CC terms, we must insist that in these instances licensors not use our trademarks, names, and logos in connection with their custom licensing arrangement".
Because SE is making the claim that the data dump is licensed CC BY-SA, but is adding non-commercial terms, they are adding an additional arrangement that "modifies or conflicts with the CC license terms".
I would be interested in if Creative Commons, as an organization, would take legal action to protect their trademarks, names, and logos.
This aspect of the change is easily resolved, however. Assuming that the data dump can be protected on its own (which is not an assumption I agree with - I do not believe that the data dump is sufficiently original or creative to receive copyright protection and then be licensed on its own), licensing it CC BY-NC-SA would resolve this (see also CC's interpretation of "noncommercial"). Even so, the content within the data dump cannot be relicensed to add these clauses and remains available for commercial use, so it's unclear what the value of calling the data dump NC would be. Claiming fair use also allows people to use material in a way that may otherwise violate copyright protection, and the primary use case that the company is trying to protect against (training AI models) is considered by CC to be fair use.

The legal status of the data dump is complicated by the existence of database rights in many parts of the world, the fact that we're using a mixture of different versions of CC-BY-SA, and the varying approaches that those versions take towards database rights. In short: It's a mess.

@Kevin Is it, considering that SE is based in the US and would likely be registering the copyright with the US Copyright Office? The US doesn't recognize database rights. This also gets into copyright law vs contract law for enforcing the CC license.

Yes, it is. Copyright and related rights exist worldwide, regardless of where (or whether) the copyright has been "registered" (indeed, some jurisdictions do not even recognize such a concept). SE may register it in the US, but that does not prevent them from enforcing it in any jurisdiction they like. Such enforcement would proceed under local laws.

Copyright is automatically assigned to the author when the work is created; it does not have to be registered anywhere for this to happen, and it applies world-wide (almost). These are basic principles of the Berne convention.

@EmilJeřábek That is true. However, in the United States (which is where I am and where I have some understanding of intellectual property), all legal options to protect work under copyright law are gated by registration. You cannot pursue a copyright claim using the CCB or the federal court system without registration. You can, however, in some cases, use contract law to enforce license agreements and terms of service.

As AMtwo pointed out in his answer the real issue is that the network Terms of Service actually include a passage that (attempts?) to grant the company a secondary license that - surprise - is far more "advantageous" for any attempt at exploiting the available content and goes an extra-mile into giving them legal grounding to simply ignore any legal and more importantly ethical requirement the Creative Common licensing had in the first place.

you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you

I don't know how or when this protocol 66 like backdoor that was strategically planted in the TOS came into being. But it is clear that this passage is the ace card that the company can try to play to claim the legality of their actions and get away with restricting the distribution of the "Subscriber Content" under their own terms.
That said, I  am not sure this is actually true. Sadly I am not a lawyer and thus I can't provide a more accurate insight but in my opinion there are two open points that should be cleared up in order to be able to verify the company claims.
Is the dual licensing legal?
While the Creative Common faqs do not strictly exclude the possibility of dual licensing, the resulting contract may be invalid due to some other "Defect of Form" or vexatious clause since the two resulting license models seems to go against each other.
Basically, we will have to verify if the company can pretend to license the content under a CC BY-SA and at the same time give itself the rights to violate the very same license.
Does the dual licensing grant the company the ability to "detach" the CC BY-SA license from any distributed content?
Even if we assume that the dual licensing is indeed legal and the company holds a second license to "distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit" the Subscriber Content, this does not directly mean that they can distribute the content only under their own terms and strip it from the CC BY-SA licensing.
The issue here should be clear. With the new download process and the requirement to digitally agree to "download the file for non-commercial use only" the company is trying to make us believe that the data dumps will be available only under their own licensing term and that their backdoor licensing allows them to distribute the Subscriber Content in a format that has been stripped from the CC BY-SA license.
I am not sure this is possible. I suspect that the CC BY-SA license is "viral" enough that it can't simply be detached by the content it covers. If this is true then the download terms could simply be rendered void since the Creative Common license is less restrictive than the secondary licensing Stack Exchange is trying to force hand on its users.

See this question for the appearance of the wording of the possible dual license. Similar (but slightly different) wording appeared in 2010. However, I'm not sure that there is any concern with the dual licensing. CC licenses are non-exclusive. There's still the question about if it's dual licensed or not, but if it is, SE gets to choose which license they use.

The interesting thing is that the non-CC license, if it exists, doesn't allow for relicensing. Although it gives the company the right to distribute the content, it doesn't seem allow the company to grant others the right to do things that would otherwise be protected, such as reproduction or distribution. In essence, it seems like if it leaves the company's hands, it must do so in the CC license.

I suspect its 'legal' - I think almost the entire problem has been not about legality, but rather that free availability of the dumps has been part of the social contract between the community and the company.
There's no legal obligation to release the dumps (only that now more that ever, the insurance the dumps provided feels comforting), but there's a moral one - as part of the old social contract that our content was ours and we'd have a way to ensure an offramp should SE go the way of other Q&A sites of the past.
Hypothetically until you've received a copy of the data - the CC rules might not kick in. Once you have your uses of it are governed by the CC licences, and you're expected to attribute, and your work can be shared the same way. SE 'as a platform' does attribute and display things as per the licence. The dump is a way to enable remixing and reuse and isn't a transformative work till it exists.
I think in general SE's savvy enough to keep things legal, doing the 'right' thing, they're occasionally less clued in about. I suspect, knowing the community that its moot anyway, since folks will figure out some way to keep the datadumps available and ongoing anyway.
